# SQL aggregate method return string if it is in set, or any other string if string is not in set

Tags: sql, sqlite

Looking for an aggregate method, or any smart approach that can result the following:

```
 - SELECT MIN_DISTANCE(set, b) FROM {a, b, c, d} set     => b 
 - SELECT MIN_DISTANCE(set, b) FROM {e, f, g} set        => e or f or g
 - SELECT MIN_DISTANCE(set, b) FROM {} set               => no result
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (case when MIN_DISTANCE(set, b) in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') then 'b'
             when MIN_DISTANCE(set, b) in ('e', 'f', 'g') MIN_DISTANCE(set, b)
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get both the matching value, and then any other rows, but actually take only the first row:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE x = 'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyTable
LIMIT 1;
```